# Not able to get the whole page source code when trying and using with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am very new to python programming, i am trying to scrape a web page

view-source:http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillDetail.asp?ID=842892230704 , this is the link for the source page.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillDetail.asp?ID=842892230704")
page_source = response.read()
print page_source
```

This is the code i am using, but when i run this in python shell, i am not getting the source page code from 257 line, and this is the code i need to scrape.

Comment: did you import urllib2?

Comment: What happens if you do a 2nd read / print after printing out page_source?  I thought response.read() should return the whole page, but it's possible, esp. if you're on a slow link, that it gets the first chunk and you have to read again to get the rest

Comment: 257 line - means the page source code line

Comment: Yeah i have imported rightly the urllib2

Comment: @user2703389 I'll note that although this problem may be "very urgent" for you - that's your concern... SO is voluntary and if people feel like answering / helping with your question - it'll be when they have the time to do so... ;) What you can help with is providing as much information as possible... eg: Why makes you think you're missing this *line*, what do you expect this *line* to contain etc...

Comment: Are you trying to read the details of someone's water bill without logging in? If the site did provide that data, it would be extremely broken.

Comment: I get a whole page ending with </html> when I paste your code into iPython.  What makes you think the file you got is incomplete?

Comment: I see the bill you're trying to scrape.  It has no numbers in it.  I assume they (and various other elements in this file) get filled in when some JavaScript runs, and/or you authenticate properly.

Comment: Hey, yeah i have logged in with the proper account number and all.

Comment: If you see the source page code, there is form tag which has a closing tag and not a opening tag, and that's the information i want to scrape. Do you guys think that no opening tag is causing this issue.

Comment: Your call to `urlopen` isn't attempting to include any cookies, so it's not going to be treated as logged in.